# Transferring to GPU in a for-loop

Tags: lua, torch

We define a tensor as follows:

```
t = torch.Tensor(10, 10, 3, 200, 200)
```

Then we assign a value to `t` and call `t:cuda()` in a loop. It takes about 10 seconds in the first iteration, but it takes 0.01 second in the next iterations. I would appreciate it if someone explains why this happens and how we can fix the problem.

Comment: Some part of that time may be due to CUDA initialization.  There might not be much that you can do about that portion.  It may help a bit if you put the GPUs in persistence mode.  Also, if you are running on a system with multiple GPUs, but don't need multiple GPUs for your app, you could set the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable before launching torch, to restrict torch to only "see" a single GPU for that run.

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what the problem is. I'd assume it's the 10 seconds, but it could easily be the 0.01s, depending on how many iterations you're doing. It's unclear.